# How to choose (change in code or similar) a variable based on a variable

Tags: python, dataframe

For example, I currently have code that is identical for contract and state which I am currently copying and pasting then performing a global find/replace to replace 'contract' with 'state'.

I'd rather loop thru and do something like:

```
for variable_name in ['contract', 'state']:
    {variable_name} = df[f'{variable_name}'].unique()
    Etc.
```

Edit - Some clarification might help.  For example, my contract code would look like...

```
contract = df['contract_name'].unique()
Etc.
```

...and my state code would look like...

```
state = df['state_name'].unique()
Etc.
```

...so I am copying the contract code and performing a find and replace where I change any occurrences of the word "contract" in the code to the word "state".  But there must be a better way?

Comment: Use a dictionary.

Comment: Seconded: use a dictionary. `unique_dict = {k: df[k].unique() for k in ['contract', 'state']}`

Comment: On second thought, I might be able to get this to work.  Stand by...